# Exclude a single file from an nginx location match

Tags: regex, nginx

I have a location on nginx like this:

```
location ~* /(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
 return 403;
 error_page 403 /403_error.html;
}
```

I have a php script that combines `css` and `js` files, and this rule wont return combined css or js file.

Is there a way to ignore this rule for one php file:

```
 /media/plg_jchoptimize/assets2/jscss.php
```

For all other files I want it to work.

Comment: This rules says that a 403 error is returned for any file with the suffixes listed in the last part, in any of the folders listed in the first part.  Is your php file in one of the folders above?  If so, you can just put it in a different folder.

Comment: no my php file runs in background, in all site. I tried to exclude folder like this location ~* /folder/to/file(images|cache|media|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {

} the combination change ~* didn't helped.

Comment: If i remove this rule the script works fine.

Comment: Ok, I see.  Let me ask this differently.  What is the URL that gets called to load the js/css file that is output from the php file?  You can obscure the domain if you want.

Comment: http://domain.com/path/to/js/file/30/0/f04fa9bac0f3d11634d7cf9205e969cf.js this is the output what the script gives that.

Comment: http://ekavet.com/ now its without the rule if i add rule ill get 403 error

Comment: http://ekavet.com/media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/nz/30/0/f04fa9bac0f3d11634d7cf9205e969cf.js

Comment: Ok thanks. So it *does* match the rule above.  One moment.

Comment: File that makes output is this one media/plg_jchoptimize/assets/jscss.php

Comment: oh i turned off url rewrite http://www.ekavet.com/media/plg_jchoptimize/assets2/jscss.php?f=7045f16f273cda202f80307edfeb656d&type=js&gz=nz&d=30&i=0

Comment: Right.  So the php file matches the regex above. So as per my first suggestion, can't you just move this file into a different directory so it isn't in /media? Or if you do want php files to run from /media, remove it from the rejex.

Comment: That file gives only output its a joomla extensions. changing file location could be very complicated. The other extension will use file upload to media directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this matching regex instead:

```
(images|cache|media(?!\/plg_jchoptimize)|logs|tmp)/.*\.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$
```

This part:

```
media(?!\/plg_jchoptimize)
```

Says *match* `media` *unless it is immediately followed by* `/plg_jchoptimize`

Comment: That what i was looking for Than You very much :)